# MP3 encoding chips?

Tags: audio, integrated-circuit

I'm looking for MP3 encoding chips 
All I found is this MAS3587f which costs about 4 $USD ?? 
Is there other cheap chips ?

Comment: That looks good to me - what is wrong with it? Don't forget that the [MP3 standard is patent encumbered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Licensing_and_patent_issues), so there are fees that need to be rolled into each one.

Comment: Now, it's patent free: _"The basic MP3 decoding and encoding technology is patent-free in the European Union, all patents having expired there by 2012 at the latest. In the United States, the technology became substantially patent-free on 16 April 2017 (see below). The majority of MP3 patents expired in the US between 2007 and 2015"_ , source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Licensing_and_patent_issues

Comment: (1) BU94702 made by Rohm.  It isn't cheap, but it is [was?] one of the few options for codec ASIC with MP3 encoding.  (2) Here's a [similar request about MP3 codec ICs on the TI support forum](http://e2e.ti.com/support/audio/f/6/t/852914) [TI has got a fair few codecs which digitize audio, but don't do MP3].  TI's suggestion is to use one of their DSPs instead of an ASIC.  (3) [MP3 library for PIC32](https://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-harmony/mplab-harmony-v2/premium-products/microchip-solutions/audio/mp3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another one is the VS1063 from the Finnish company VLSI Solution (http://www.vlsi.fi), although $4 seems like a great price -- the VS1063 is $25 each for 1-99, only goes down to $4.80 each for 1000+ pieces.

Comment: Indeed, $4 is much better than $25. :-)